# Definition and use of a Boolean equation system

Tags: boolean-algebra

According to google, a *system of boolean equations* is defined as follows

> Essentially, a Boolean equation system is an ordered sequence of fixed point equations over Boolean variables, with associated signs, µ and ν, specifying the polarity of the fixed points. The equations are of the form σx = α, where α is a positive Boolean expression.

After reading a bit more, my interpretation is as follows. Is my interpretation correct?

For each variable $x_i$ we have a boolean formula without negations and for each such $x_i$ we also have a "preferred" assignment (0 or 1). It is the highest priority to assign a value to each variable so that the formula for $x_0$ is such that $x_0$ assumes its preferred value, even if it means that all other variables must assume their non-preferred value. After that (regardless of whether it failed for $x_0$), the next top priority is to try to have $x_1$ assume its preferred value, etc.

The main question is, what could possibly be the use of such a system? I don't mean a use in real life, but can it e.g. be used to help solving more conventional problems?

Comment: SAT is equivalent to satisfiability of a system of Boolean equations.

Answer (score 1):

I am not used to this definition.  Instead, the definition I am used to states that a system of boolean equations has the form

$$\begin{align*}
f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n)&=0\\
\vdots\\
f_m(x_1,\dots,x_n)&=0.
\end{align*}$$

where $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are boolean variables and $f_1,\dots,f_m$ are boolean functions.  The values $v_1,\dots,v_n$ are a solution to the system of equations iff $f_i(v_1,\dots,v_n)=0$ for all $i$.

This is useful, for instance, in formal verification.  For example, $f_i$ might represent one bit of output of some boolean circuit.